# How to change only the second parameter of an onclick function when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I have an onclick handler with two parameters. When it's clicked I want to update only the second parameter value. I prefer jQuery.

I have tried all kinds of jQuery combinations.

The included code works but I want to exclude replacing the first parameter.

The link:

```
<a href="#" id="messageremove" onclick="messageremove('param1', 'param2')"
```

The jQuery code:

```
$("#messageremove").attr('onclick', 'messageremove(' + "'" + param1 + "'" + ', ' + "'" + param2_new + "'" + ')');
```

I want to exclude replacing the first parameter, but right now both are being replaced.

Comment: Seems to me like an *XY problem*... What are those params actually? What's your end goal? Can you describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variables, store the before variable and the new variable. Then update accordingly. I just switched them in this exmaple.

```js
let before = '';
let after = '';

function messageremove(param1, param2) {
  before = param1;
  after = param2;
   $("#messageremove").attr('onclick', `messageremove(`+ after + `,` + before + `)`)
  console.log($("#messageremove").attr('onclick'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" id="messageremove" onclick="messageremove('before', 'new')">Switch</a>
```

Comment: `unbind()` has no effect on an inline  `onclick`. It is also a deprecated method

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for that, I forgot I left that there. I was testing other things and forgot to remove.

Comment: Thanks all, I didn't got any email notifications so sorry for the late response!